# GWT чтение из файла

Tags: java, файлы, исключения, gwt

Пытаюсь читать из файла на стороне сервера:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("text.txt");
```

файл text.txt лежит в той же папке что и html (в корне папки war).
При развертыванию на Tomcat, получаю "File not found"
Подскажите, какой путь нужно указать ?

Comment: Покажите структуру, пожалуйста

Comment: При таком использовании он ищет файл от точки запуска, т.е. от местоположения `java` (`java.exe`)

Comment: Методом "подкидывания файла" определил, что находит файл по адресу :  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите читать файлы из корня web-проекта (war'ника), то необходимо использовать [ServletContext#getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-). Можете ознакомится с другими вариантами чтения по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app)